# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Instance '<UserLog at 0x1f10dc38680>' is not persistent within this Session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I try to insert a record in a table in Python 3.10 using Alchemy
I create a userLog: UserLog object to insert in a table  users_log
In order to insert, I do

On my main.py function I have

```
@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exception: RequestValidationError):
    await track_errors(str(request.url), str(exception.body), str(exception))
    return JSONResponse(status_code=HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                        content=str(exception),
                        status=HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)))

async def track_errors(url: str, request_body: str, response: str):
    user_log = await create_user_log_error_trace(url, request_body, response)
    session = await anext(get_session())
    user_log_service = UserLogService(session)
    await user_log_service.save(user_log)
```

I get the session of the database with

```
sync def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    database_url = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{DATABASE_URI}"
    engine = create_async_engine(
        database_url, pool_recycle=3600, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_size=5, max_overflow=0, echo=_ECHO, future=True
    )
    async_session = sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
```

Save function is

```
 async def save(self, userLog: UserLog) -> NoReturn:
        """
        Args:
            userLog (UserLog): New UserLog Model object

        Returns:
            int: Saved userLog_id
        """
        self.session.add(userLog)
        await self.session.commit()
        await self.session.refresh(userLog)
```

self.session.add(userLog) is executing successful
but when I try to execute
await self.session.commit()
it's rasing an exception:
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Instance '<UserLog at 0x1f10dc38680>' is not persistent within this Session

And I can't insert the data, it's like the session which is open it was closed abruptly.

Please, can anyone help me with this?

I want to insert the object userlog on the table users_log

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing, Instance <UserLog at 0x1f10dc38680> is not persistent within this Session, typically happens when you're trying to perform operations on an object associated with a different session or a session that has been closed.

Your session is managed by the context manager async with async_session as session:. This means that once you exit the context of the async with block, the session is closed.

Here's a key part of your code where the issue lies:

```
async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    # ...
    async with async_session as session:
        yield session
```

When yield is called, the function is paused and control is transferred back to the caller. After the caller is finished, control returns to the point in the function where yield was called. If yield was inside an async with block, the block is exited at this point and the session is closed.

To fix the issue, you can try making your get_session function a context manager:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    database_url = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{DATABASE_URI}"
    engine = create_async_engine(
        database_url, pool_recycle=3600, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_size=5, max_overflow=0, echo=_ECHO, future=True
    )
    async_session = sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
    session = async_session()
    try:
        yield session
        await session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        await session.rollback()
        raise e
    finally:
        await session.close()
```